# What is the size of processor register and how many processor registers are there?

Tags: c++, c

I declared an `int` variable as follows:

```
register int count;
```

When a variable is declared as `register`, its allocation would be done in the processor on which my computer is running.

My question is, how many processor registers are there, and what is the size of those registers?

Comment: Depends on the processor - Arm, Sparc, Power, Mips, x86, x86-64,  Alpha, system z, Itanium, and many more.. They are all different.

Comment: You don't need to use the `register` keyword, as the compiler will automatically place variables in registers.

Comment: `register` in C is only a hint. It does not require the compiler keep the object in a register

Comment: In C ++ `register` is not a storage class specifier and does nothing.

Comment: Is this a C question or a C++ question? The answers will be very different.

Comment: Don't use the `register` storage class. It's pretty much obsoleted by optimizing compilers.

Comment: @Felix Palmen C with no extensions you are right. But sometimes in  uController  programming it is needed to permanently bind variable to the register. Nowadays actually it is not used as often as in 8 bit era but it is possible for example avr gcc **`register unsigned char counter asm("r3");`**

Comment: @PeterJ if you need it, you *know* it. If you have to ask how many registers there are, you don't need it :)

Comment: @Felix Palmen :D

Comment: The number and size of processor registers is architecture dependent.  Refer to your processor user manual.  This is a hardware question, and so off-topic for SO.

Answer (score 9):

> When a variable is declared as register, its allocation would be done in the processor by which my computer is running.

This is ancient knowledge from many decades ago. Nowadays, the keyword `register` in C is a largely-ignored hint, and in C++ it does literally nothing; since C++17 you're not even allowed to write it any more (it's "unused and reserved").

Compilers since the 1990s are smart enough to decide where to put (or not put!) data, and they more or less ignore your insistence that you know better (unless you have very specific hardware requirements, which would require more specific code anyway).

Instead of trying to leak physical factors into your codebase, just write nice code that describes the *semantics* of your program, remembering that both C++ and (to a slightly lesser extent) C are *abstractions*, not a one-to-one mapping to machine instructions.

As for how many processor registers exist and with what size, that depends entirely on which processor you have. You can probably find out from its datasheet, if you are *really* curious.